# armv7 - monitor/wait like x86?

Tags: arm, monitoring, interrupt

I am reading the armv7 architecture documentation and -possibly- missed the ability for the architecture to monitor/wait on a range of address, like x86.

On arm an approaching concept is `wfe`.

It is useful to create an interrupt in case your program accesses a range of memory outside of what it should. That enables you to deal with it at the OS level/callback.

**Did I miss it or is it non existent?**

Thanks

Comment: I can't quite parse the exact question here (maybe it's x86 terminology I'm not familiar with) -  the first paragraph sounds like it's about debug watchpoints, while the second sounds like it's about the MMU. Either way, both of those are definitely a thing...

Comment: Ah, I see, there is a specific x86 thing. I can't claim sufficient knowledge after 3 minutes of searching the web, but I'd suggest perhaps taking a look at WFE and associated events.

Comment: I had a look at wfe but it seems to not answer to a memory range. I may be wrong, I don't know armv7 properly yet.

Comment: There is also the ETM, performance monitors and numerous DEBUG registers.

Comment: @artlessnoise: I know they are different architecture, but I need that functionality, and I am just asking :) The goal is to firmly prevent the process to access some ranges of memory at runtime, to avoid bad behaviors. It is for a custom unix OS. Trustzone seems not be the right tool. Could `wfe` manage range of adresses?

Comment: If you don't want a process to access certain areas of memory, then don't map them into that process. That's what MMUs exist for.

Comment: `wfe` is used for cpu-to-cpu signaling afaik.  If you want finer grained control than the MMU, then the debug registers may work.  An ARM SOC may have non-standard functionality to use.  For instance, the TrustZone bus protection could be used for this.  Some SOC have non-TZ bus protection functional blocks.  Just saying you want `monitor` and `wait` is not helpful.  How exactly do you intend to use them and for what?   The instructions don't exist on the ARM.  I need that functionality is not helpful.  Describe what you use them for.

Comment: Having done a bit more reading, I don't see how you could "firmly prevent" a process accessing memory by waking up a sleeping core _after_ said process has _overwritten_ that memory anyway. In terms of the intended usage for synchronisation (e.g. waiting on a lock) it does seem a pretty close parallel to events - the difference on ARM being that it's down to the guy doing the write to perform a `sev` to notify any waiters, rather than some magic monitoring hardware (indeed in ARMv8, a successful 'unlock' write via `strex` and friends will generate such an event itself).

Comment: The whole purpose is to have a single address space virtual memory system and to lock a process in its own virtual memory window/frame. This is not a general purpose kernel though.